# Why is my SQL insert statement failing to execute through my php script?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, syntax, syntax-error

In a php script, I've attempted an insert statement several different ways:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table (charfield,charfield,intfield,decimalfield) VALUES ('$stringvar','$stringvar',$intvar,$decimalvar)";
$query = "INSERT INTO table (charfield,charfield,intfield,decimalfield) VALUES ('".$stringvar."','".$stringvar."',".$intvar.",".$decimalvar.")";
$query = 'INSERT INTO table (charfield,charfield,intfield,decimalfield) VALUES ("'.$stringvar.'","'.$stringvar.'",'.$intvar.','.$decimalvar.')';
$query = 'INSERT INTO table (charfield,charfield,intfield,decimalfield) VALUES ("'.$stringvar.'","'.$stringvar.'","'.$intvar.'","'.$decimalvar.'")';
```

I've executed it several different ways too using combinations of these:

```
mysql_real_escape_string($query);
mysql_query($query);
$result = @mysql_query($query);
```

I've echo'd out the statement that is being concatenated and it looks fine.  Even if I copy and paste that into phpmyadmin sql editor, it executes fine.  The database is MySQL and the user has the correct permissions.

What am I doing wrong?

---

**EDIT:**

Error message using `or die`:

```
Access denied for user 'schaffins'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

I've added a user with the rights to select, insert, and update and I'm connecting using that user in the php before executing anything.

Also, I was able to insert into another table I made in the same script.

Comment: Is error reporting enabled? also is there anything returned from mysql_error()?

Comment: When you say it fails, can you give us more information - Do you mean it executes but nothing is inserted, or do you get an error and if so what is the error message

Comment: `mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error())` and it will tell you what's wrong.

Comment: Do other queries work?  Have you tried reducing this insert to a smaller one?  Have you tried terminating the query with a semicolon? "Table" is the actual name of the table in your actual code, I assume. Seeing the table definition might be helpful, as would actual values you are putting into strfield. I also recommend using PDO instead of manually concatenating SQL (http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: This may be a silly question, but you have specfiied the password in mysql_connect() haven't you? Because its saying you are not using the password...
FYI the "@" infront of "@mysql_query($query);" is supressing the error message that would have been displayed. Fine for production, but not so helpful for testing!

Comment: I just tried semicolons on the 4 different flavors of syntax.  I'll check out PDO... also looking to try using placeholders for the vars and sending through with the execute

Comment: I think that when mysql gets the statement, the int and decimal values might be getting interpreted as strings?  Not too sure...

Comment: Other queries work - both selects and inserts... just not on this specific one for some reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes the database connection happens only after certain actions &| validations take place.  Make sure you have an open connection before attempting to execute any sql.  If the connection is nested within an if/else code block, the conditions may not be satisfied and the db connection will not be established.

Try finding the db connection and moving (or copying) to a more 'globalized' location within the php - aka somewhere in the php that ensures the db connection is made before any if statements that might exclude the connection from being established based on conditionals that aren't allowing

Answer (score 2):

This issue isn't with your insert - the error is connecting to the database so its not even getting as far as running the insert statement.

Double-check the credentials you are passing into mysql_connect()... from the error message "Access denied for user 'schaffins'@'localhost' (using password: NO)" it appears the problem is with your password.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `mysql_real_escape_string` on the entire query.  That will escape quotes that are part of the query syntax.  You need to use it on the values to insert in the query.

Comment: I commented it out on a couple runs and it made no difference